# Dismissing a shared instance viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an issue that i can't resolve. On my login page, i am creating a shared instance and loading it:

```
ViewController *vc = [ViewController sharedInstance];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.1) {
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}else{
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

This works well for the first time.
On my view controller, i have a logoff method that looks like this:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.1) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];       
}else{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

It also works well, but after i logoff, and try to login again, it stops in the middle of the code… No error, no excuses.

Anyone knows a solution?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Method for `sharedInstance`

```
static ViewController *vcontroller; 
+ (ViewController *) sharedInstance { 
    if (!vcontroller) { 
        vcontroller = [[ViewController alloc] init]; 
    } return vcontroller; 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of sharedInstance.. Help me to help you..

Comment: static ViewController *vcontroller = nil;
+ (ViewController*) sharedInstance {
    if (!vcontroller) {
        vcontroller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return vcontroller;
}

Comment: [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; try to dismiss with this line & check...

Comment: same this line [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: "it stops in the middle of the code" -- what does that mean?

Comment: @user1461635 don't add code as a comment -- instead update your question

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I thing U really want (should) to remove the shared instance. So make sure you have a method for setting the cController static variable to nil in you code. I dont think calling sharedInstance and setting that will work since it seems like you are using singleton and if you have the proper implementation of singleton pattern it will not work. 
Also you may be able to clear this variable right be lore login to based on your requirements